# Linq join - add result to property

Tags: linq, join, properties, mapping, assign

I have an Alert class, with for example 10 properties. Two of the properties are [NotMapped] -

Then in my controller, I'm using Linq to join two tables to get the Alert class and a Customer class.

From the Customer class, there are two properties (customerName and customerAdmin) that I want to assign to the Alert class.

At the moment I'm doing this.....

```
var Alerts = (from a in alertrepository.Alerts
                      join code..........
                            Alerts = a
                            Customer = b
                        .................
                            select new Alert { 
                            alertID = a.alertID,
                            applicantName = a.applicantName,
                            applicantEmail = a.applicantEmail,
                            applicantTelephone = a.applicantTelephone,
                            location = a.location,
                            dateSubmitted = a.dateSubmitted,
                     This - alertCustomerName= b.customerName,
                     This - alertCustomerAdmin= b.customerAdmin,
                            }).ToList();
```

Instead of having to declare a new Alert class again, and manually fill every property again as I am doing, is there any quicker way just to add individual properties?

For example, select a { a.alertCustomerName = b.customerName etc}

Comment: Does `Alert` have a `customer` property? BTW if this is Entity Framework you can't create `Alert` objects in the same query.

Comment: Alert has a alertCustomerName, and alertCustomerAdmin property which are the 2 that need updating from the Customer object. The above is working, but just thought there may be a quicker way to fill 2 properties, rather than having to manually re-write the whole Alert model inside the linq.

Comment: Yes... but does it have a `customer` property? You could use AutoMapper.

Comment: No it doesn't  - bit new to mvc, so not sure about Automapper?

Comment: If there is `customer` property, AutoMapper can resolve properties like `customerName` in the target object. Read about it here: https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flattening

Comment: Hi - had a quick read and that seems to be what I'm after. Thanks for your help.